# Django request.POST.get does not save to model field

Tags: django, post, methods, modelform

I am trying to save data from request.POST dictionary. I would like to get the the 'name' value from request.POST which should correspond to the prefix. However, it does not happen and nothing gets saved to Name model. Also, I get no error. Could you please kindly advise how to solve this case? Thank you.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import pdb

model_names = ['A', 'B']

def get_assumptions(request):

    AssumptionFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

    if request.method == 'POST':



        formsets = [AssumptionFormset(request.POST, prefix=thing) for thing in model_names]

        if all([formset.is_valid() for formset in formsets]):

            for formset in formsets:

                for form in formset:

                    form.save(commit=False)
                    form.Name = request.POST.get('name')
                    form.save()   



    else:

        formsets = [AssumptionFormset(prefix=thing) for thing in model_names]

    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formsets': formsets})
```

**assumptions.html**

```
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
{% for formset in formsets %} 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }} 
    <h1>{{formset.prefix}}</h1>
    <table id="formset" class="form">
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <thead><tr>
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr></thead>
    {% endif %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <td>
            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
            {{ field }}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id={{formset.prefix}} name={{formset.prefix}} />
{% endfor %}    
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['Name']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Base = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Comment: django post method for get value you can use form.Name = request.POST['name']

Comment: Thanks for insight. I did it as well, however still does not save to database and no error generated. Yet when i debug request.POST['name'] contains 'B'. Wonder why it is not saved to Name field in db. Additional suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass `"name=name"` and `"value={{formset.prefix}}"` in your HTML form.

```
<input type="hidden" id={{formset.prefix}} name="name" value="{{formset.prefix}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for insight. I did it, however still does not save to database and no error generated. Yet when i debug request.POST.get('name') contains 'B'. Wonder why it is not saved to Name field in db. Additional suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Martin check if you have any other form errors. Does other attributes get saved?

Comment: all other inputted values in the Base, Worst, Best fields do get saved, except this name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. The reason is that instance of the model was not created. Code should be as follows:

```
for form in formset:

    assumption_data = form.save(commit=False)
    assumption_data.Name = request.POST['name']
    assumption_data.save()
```

where assumptions_data is an instance of Assumptions model. Thank you everyone for insights provided.